# How to compile dynamic template from outside of angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to load dynamic HTML content via AJAX, then compile it, because it contains angular directives.

I have [this class](https://gist.github.com/umidjons/1fb8ae674df4c71f85cf) that uses methods that help using angular without being in the scope of an angular controller or directive:

```
var AngularHelper = (function () {
    var AngularHelper = function () { };

    /**
     * ApplicationName : Default application name for the helper
     */
    var defaultApplicationName = "MyApp";

    /**
         * Compile : Compile html with the rootScope of an application
         *  and replace the content of a target element with the compiled html
         * @$targetDom : The dom in which the compiled html should be placed
         * @htmlToCompile : The html to compile using angular
         * @applicationName : (Optionnal) The name of the application (use the default one if empty)
         */
    AngularHelper.Compile = function ($targetDom, htmlToCompile, applicationName) {
        var $injector = angular.injector(["ng", applicationName || defaultApplicationName]);

        $injector.invoke(["$compile", "$rootScope", function ($compile, $rootScope) {
                        //Get the scope of the target, use the rootScope if it does not exists
            var $scope = $targetDom.html(htmlToCompile).scope();
            $compile($targetDom)($scope || $rootScope);
            $rootScope.$digest();
        }]);
    }
    return AngularHelper;
})();
```

Then I use it after my jQuery successful ajax request:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>AngularJS Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="contents"><!-- content --></div>
        <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $.get( "http://fuiba.com/test/index.html", function( data ) {
                    $("#result").html(data);
                    AngularHelper.Compile('$("#result")', data);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But I get this error (see this [<kbd>codepen</kbd>](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xVLVVv)):

> $targetDom.html is not a function

Comment: In this line 

`AngularHelper.Compile('$("#result")', data);` 
you're passing string (`'$("#result")'`) for argument `$targetDom` but later in function you act with it like with jQuery object by calling `.html` function on it. String class of course doesn't have such method.

Comment: @RytisAlekna Thanks to you and MiTa the problem is solved, but I get another error. See this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xVLVVv).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a DOM element not a string as a first parameter in `AngularHelper.Compile` function,

so

`AngularHelper.Compile($("#result"), data);`

not

`AngularHelper.Compile('$("#result")', data);`

Comment: Thank you so much @MiTa!! the problem is solved, but I get another error: `Module 'MyApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.` [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xVLVVv)

Comment: Look at line 41 `angular.module('MyApp')` you are just getting this module, but you have to create it `angular.module('MyApp',[])`

Comment: I don't know why this _AngularHelper_ class works perfectly for others and not for me. I get another error:  `$targetDom.html(...).scope is not a function`. I will try to solve it! Thank you!!